IPv4 vs IPv6 source address through tunnel
I have two VPS <-> Router Wireguard tunnels separate for IPv4 and v6 and doing routing to an IP-checking website through tunnel. If I would disable NATv4, my traffic would be blocked by gateway as one with wrong source address. However, I don't have NATv6, so the website shows my IPv4 of VPS and IPv6 of a PC behind home router. Traceroute shows both IP protocols are going through tunnel to reach the website.
As for me it looks correct since v6 routing is different, I had an argue whether it's a misconfiguration of my or VPS-provider's network. Is this a correct behavior and how is it explained?

What IPv6 address range did you use for the IPv6 tunnel? Is the "IPv6 of a PC behind home router" address issued by your VPS provider or by your local ISP? (Side question: Why have two separate tunnels at all?)

@grawity_u1686 in home network I have dualstack, my local ISP gives me /64 so that is used to access internet.

That doesn't quite answer any of the three questions I had... So you route ::/0 through the tunnel, but your hosts don't actually have any IPv6 address from the tunnel?

@grawity_u1686 yes, for testing purpose I do route ::/0 through tunnel. Locally I use a prefix that is assigned by ISP. Tests are done through https://ip6only.me/ - traceroute shows I'm going to it through tunnel, but website itself shows I have local IPv6


Locally I use a prefix that is assigned by ISP

Your VPS provider's network is likely misconfigured, i.e. lacking the usual ingress filtering to make sure customers can only send from the provider's addresses. (Not in the sense of misconfigured protocol – triangular routing is not against any IP specification – but in the sense of not following Best Practices for preventing the network from being used for attacks.) With proper filtering at the provider, your traceroute would still go through the tunnel but die before exiting the provider's network.
It's very common for providers to deploy IPv6 at a much later date than IPv4, and as a result forget to apply some of the configuration they had done for IPv4.

As for me it looks correct since v6 routing is different,

IPv6 routing isn't actually different from IPv4 routing. Their routing tables are separate but most of the concepts remain the same.
What's different is that a provider can afford to assign you more addresses in IPv6 compared to IPv4, removing the need of NAT – which otherwise has the same task regardless of address version: it's mainly there to let you connect more devices than you have public IP addresses. But if you had a sufficiently large IPv4 address range, you could just as well route IPv4 through your tunnel without any NAT.
